# Converting a string field to a collection set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

**Background Info**: When a user signs up on the site they must provide an email. Currently a take their email domain and compare it with the email domain of a Company I have in the admin. If the domain is the same then I put the user in a list of Company "employees." The domain is of type `string`

**Objective**: Assign multiple domains to a Company.

How can I create a string field that will take multiple domains? I have tried separating domains by a comma and parsing through the string to see if the domain a user inputs is valid but it seems like there must be a better way to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would create a new model and database table for Domain where domain belongs_to company and company has_many domains.

If that's not possible, your solution isn't too bad if the user selects the company they are with and so you are only looking up one company record to validate, however it looks like you are looking up the company by domain name, in which case

If you have to look up the company by domain, you have options, depending on your database. With mysql, you have the FIND_IN_SET function you can use like this:

```
Company.where("FIND_IN_SET(?, domain)", params[:domain])
```

In Postgres you have this (I wasn't able to test, so some assembly may be required):

```
Company.where("? = ANY (string_to_array(domain,',')", params[:domain])
```

A word of caution: you may have companies that allow users to use a personal email like example@gmail.com. In this case, a domain name may be duplicated across multiple companies.